# Hibernate jpa sub object not saving

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to Hibernate and JPA in Spring, so this is probably a beginner error. I'm having trouble persisting an object with its association.

For example:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
Breed breed = dao.getBreedById(1); (gets persistent object)

dog.setName("Pluto");
dog.setBreed(breed);

save(dog);
```

The dog and all fields save, but the breed association does not save in the database. I don't get any errors. It just doesn't save. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I traced the issue to an annotation that had been in place ... that left me hitting myself afterwards. -.-

I had:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "breed_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Breed breed;
```

Sigh. Removing the insertable and updatable clause fixed the problem.

Comment: maybe mentioning what "save" does would help??! and mentioning what is in the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You save the dog into the DB. If what you want is breed have the dog, you should set this manually as well. There is no auto-relation in JPA

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
Breed breed = dao.getBreedById(1); (gets persistent object)

dog.setName("Pluto");
dog.setBreed(breed);
breed.getDogCollection.add(dog);//you have to maintain relationship manually

save(dog);
```

Comment: i actually traced the problem to a slightly different issue, but thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: so if the problem was something else why not add the answer yourself, rather than accepting something that is not the answer?